# How to get the choice selection to show up in a label in a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how to select an option from a picker view, and have that choice appear in a new view controller. For example, I want to select a city in a drop down menu and have that city appear in a label in a new view controller. The picture is how I coded to create the picker view. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AufpF.png)

Comment: First of all read about the `UIPickerView` for dropdown [click here for `UIPickerView` example](https://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/) And then read about push and pop view controllers in IOS for moving to new viewcontroller [click here for passing data between `UIViewControllers`](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropdown you can use a UIAlertCocntroller with style actionsheet. Place the ALertAction in for loop so as to make cities appear in a list. Perform all this on a button click.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

for(NSString *str array){
    UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:str style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [self.button setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
    [alert addAction:button];
}

UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
}];
[alert addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```